# How do I use Axios GET Params using a search input

Tags: axios

I'm trying to send GET request and I also want to fetch the data using the search input. So I have used Params but it is not working ,
here's my code :

````
 // setFetching(true)
 let url = `${TEST_API_URL}/teammember/getAll`
 try {
   const posts: any = await axios.get(`${url}`, {
     withCredentials: true,
     headers: {
       Authorization: `${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`,
     },
     params: {
       search
     },
   })
   console.log(posts.data.Data)
   setPosts(posts.data.Data)
 } catch (error: any) {
   toast.error('Something went wrong')
 }
 // setFetching(false)
}, [search])

useEffect(() => {
 async function fetchData() {
   await fetchFunction()
 }
 void fetchData()
}, [fetchFunction])```
````

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to do like this.

````
 // setFetching(true)
 let url = `${TEST_API_URL}/teammember/getAll`
 try {
   const posts: any = await axios.get(`${url}?search=${search}`, {
     withCredentials: true,
     headers: {
       Authorization: `${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`,
     }
   })
   console.log(posts.data.Data)
   setPosts(posts.data.Data)
 } catch (error: any) {
   toast.error('Something went wrong')
 }
 // setFetching(false)
}, [search])

useEffect(() => {
 async function fetchData() {
   await fetchFunction()
 }
 void fetchData()
}, [fetchFunction])```
````

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working